# django aggregation over joining model

Tags: django

Lets say I have 3 models

```
class User(models.Model):
    pass

class Content(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Like(models.model):
    liked_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.ForeignKey(Content, related_name='likes')
```

How do I use aggregation to work out the top users got most likes?

I tried:

`result = Like.objects.annotate(num_liked=Count('item__created_by'))`

But this returns the like objects, doesn't seem legit.

Answer (score 0):

I think I worked it out, but requires someone to verify this for me:

`User.objects.annotate(liked=Count('content__likes'))`